# Inconsistent I/O when reading int from DataInputStream

Tags: java, datainputstream, dataoutputstream

I have a client-server topology in which the client asks for a listing of the directories or files in the current working directory on the server, and the server replies with the appropriate information.

See client code

```
controlSocket.writeByte(LSDIR);
int dirCount = controlSocket.readInt();
Map<String, Long> dirMap = new HashMap<>();

for (int i = 0; i < dirCount; i++) {
    dirMap.put(controlSocket.readString(), controlSocket.readLong());
}
```

and server code

```
dir = new File(cwd);
output.writeInt(dir.listFiles(File::isDirectory).length);

for (File file : dir.listFiles(File::isDirectory)){
    output.writeUTF(file.getName());
    output.writeLong(file.lastModified());
}
```

Now when I don't change the directory on the server the directory listing works just fine, no matter how many times I call it. However, if I cd using this client code

```
controlSocket.writeByte(CD);
controlSocket.writeString(path);
```

and this server code

```
String inputDir = input.readUTF();
if (inputDir.equals("..")) {
    cwd = cwd.substring(0, cwd.lastIndexOf("/"));
} else {
    cwd += "/" + inputDir;
}
```

the directory listing runs but the integer that is read from the socket is not what the server sends (ex. on the server I see 1 is sent, but on the client something like 16777216 is read). The server reads the directory content with no problem, so there is no issue on this side.

It seems like the Data I/O Stream is not consistent, or else I'm missing out on something. Note that both the client and the server run on the same machine.

Comment: Double check your reads and writes. You're not trying to imply that `DataStreams` would be broken, are you?

Comment: I just double checked the order in which I read and write, but I still get the incorrect integer on the other end. Maybe my implementation of the DataStreams is wrong, or I found some arrangement in which they get broken.

Comment: What is `readString()`? What for that matter is `controlSocket`? Data that is written with `writeUTF()` must be read with `readUTF()`.

Comment: controlSocket is a TLSClient object, and the readString() method is from TLSClient which calls the readUTF() method of the underlying SSLSocket.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the server wrote an additional confirmation boolean after changing the directory, which was read by the client as the integer.

So the code up here is working without any problem.